# Replacing problems in string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a problem to replacings in a string: I want to change all the appearances from 2h / 2h / 2 heure / 2heure / 2 heures / 2heures to #hour. I tried:

```
text = "I should leave the house at 16h45 but I am late and I should not be arriving between 2 h or 3h or maybe 4heures"
hour = re.compile(r'[0-9]+\s?(h|heures?)([0-9]+)?')
replaces = hour.sub('#hour', text)
print(replaces)
```

Output:

> I should leave the house at #hour but I am late and I should not be arriving between #hour or #hour or maybe **#houreures**

Good output:

> I should leave the house at #hour but I am late and I should not be arriving between #hour or #hour or maybe **#hour**

How could I solve this problem **#houreures**?

Comment: Do you currently understand why the problem is occurring?

Comment: `[0-9]+\s?(heures?|h)([0-9]+)?` should work. In your case, you are saying that if h is not found then see if heures is present. The thing is, whenever heures is present, h will always be present (its the first character of heures). So, you need to change the ordering. You should first search for heures, and if that is not present, then search for h

Comment: Yes, thank you @BenQuigley I had not thought! I use an '|' operator, so program stops at 'h'. Great, it's clear now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `h` alternative matched the `h` in `heures` and `heures?` alternative was not even tested. Swapping the alternatives can solve the problem, but it is a better idea to use an optional non-capturing group instead (see solution below).

There is no need in the capturing parentheses in the pattern, I suggest removing them (or, if you want to use alternation, convert to a non-capturing group).

Besides, the `([0-9]+)?` pattern can be simplified to `[0-9]*`.

You may use

```
[0-9]+\s?h(?:eures?)?[0-9]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oLUvnY/1)

**Details**

- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `\s?` - 1 or 0 whitespaces
- `h` - a `h` letter
- `(?:eures?)?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of `eure` or `eures`
- `[0-9]*` - 0 or more digits.

See the [Python demo](http://I%20should%20leave%20the%20house%20at%20#hour%20but%20I%20am%20late%20and%20I%20should%20not%20be%20arriving%20between%20#hour%20or%20#hour%20or%20maybe%20#hour):

```
import re
text = "I should leave the house at 16h45 but I am late and I should not be arriving between 2 h or 3h or maybe 4heures"
hour = re.compile(r'[0-9]+\s?h(?:eures?)?[0-9]*')
replaces = hour.sub('#hour', text)
print(replaces)
# => I should leave the house at #hour but I am late and I should not be arriving between #hour or #hour or maybe #hour
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the ordering of `heures` and `h` inside the parenthesis, like this:

`[0-9]+\s?(heures?|h)([0-9]+)?` should work.

In case of `(h|heures?)`, you are saying that if `h` is not found then see if `heures` is present. The thing is, whenever `heures` is present, `h` will always be present (its the first character of `heures`). So, you need to change the ordering. You should first search for `heures`, and if that is not present, **then** search for `h`. So, replacing  `(h|heures?)` with `(heures?|h)` solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch the [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) because the h in the first part gets matched first.

In for example `4heures`, your regex matches one or more times a digit `\d+`. Then in the alternation `(h|heures?)` it can match the `h` from `heures`. In the replacement the matched `4h` will be replaced with `#hour` resulting in `#houreures`

[`[0-9]+\s?(heures?|h)([0-9]+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/9WR91J/1)

```
import re

text = "I should leave the house at 16h45 but I am late and I should not be arriving between 2 h or 3h or maybe 4heures"
hour = re.compile(r'[0-9]+\s?(heures?|h)([0-9]+)?')
replaces = hour.sub('#hour', text)
print(replaces)
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/BYRN34964)

Answer (score 1):

Online demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/J2khU2/2).

```
import re

text = "I should leave the house at 16h45 but I am late and I should not be arriving between 2 h or 3h or maybe 4heures"

s = re.sub(r'\d+\s*[h]?(eure)*[s]?\d*', '#hour', text)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
I should leave the house at #hour but I am late and I should not be arriving between #hour or #hour or maybe #hour
```